# Developing REST API using PHP

Tags: php

I am new in API. I am supposed to develop an API that allows our content provider to give information pertaining soccer whereby he is supposed to create matches,update matches etc .I would like to know how to create a REST API in php that allows a client to enter the information. So far,I have created an API but I dont know how to enable the client enter the information.

Comment: Please share your code first han we can able to give advice.

Answer (score 0):

### Informations:

It is the basic form that you have to create and then you must allow the user to submit the form datas that he/she has filled and you have to post the data to the route that you have created.

- You must submit the data and then you have to make the submitted data to be `json_encode()` so that it will work for the API.

Or Else if you are not designing the form and other such things you can directly go in for the API ADD ONS that the Firefox and the chrome has . Assuming you are using the chrome or Firefox as browsers.

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: thanks Naresh for your quick response. please help me understand how to post the data to the route

Comment: @Naresh.I already have postman.I I told you my problem is how to post the data to the route

Comment: @Nmorry. I am using Laravel for building the API and it is the best for developing the API. Since many options are available for developing the API with ease

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming that you created a REST API already, download the Advanced REST client chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

I hope that answers to your question.

P.S: May I know what framework did you use to design your REST API ? Additional details can help you further.

Comment: Nice, you but can try using Slim Framework.
Slim framework is a lightweight yet simple framework to use for REST APIs, I have used it a lot ! 
Try this tutorial: [Tutorial link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-restful-api-framework-slim-tutorial-1/)

Using a framework can make it easier for you, bro ! :)

Comment: thanks Mega. Let me try it and I will get back to you incase of any assistance

Comment: Sure thing ;) !

Comment: Hi Mega I am back.After creating the API and testing it with Rest client it is working.Now my worry is how will the client(content provider) get the page that he will enter so that it is posted to my database via the API

Comment: Okay, I don't seem to understand what you're saying but I think you must be asking how to do "URL routing via REST api" ?

Answer (score 0):

Building REST APIs is atually a rather easy task. That's primarily what I work on at work all day. If you have to use PHP (I'm a fan of PHP, so don't take that comment the wrong way :) ), I would reccommend using a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

The logic to handle the information once it's requested wouldn't change. You would just need to make your requests/responses REST compliant.

[Here](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-build-restful-apis-using-php-and-laravel/how-to/2014/08/13) is a great tutorial for doing just that!

Also, since you use Yii, [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) is probably better. I've never used Yii, so I can't really vouch for it, though.

Comment: Thanks Zac.However, I have never used laravel. I am used to yii2.Do have a link that can guide me through the same?

Comment: Updated the answer :)